# Will goroutine leakage happen that channel with one buffer which have two inputs but only one output?

Tags: go

I have a function that is used to forward a message between two `io.ReadWriter`s.  Once an error happens, I need to log the error and return. But I think I may have a goroutine leakage problem in my code:

```
func transport(rw1, rw2 io.ReadWriter) error {
    errc := make(chan error, 1) // only one buffer
    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(rw1, rw2)
        errc <- err
    }()

    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(rw2, rw1)
        errc <- err
    }()

    err := <-errc // only one error catched
    if err != nil && err == io.EOF {
        err = nil
    }
    return err
}
```

Because there is only one error can be caught in this function, will the second goroutine exit and garbaged normally? Or should I write one more `err <- errc` to receive another error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value from one goroutine is received and the other is buffered. Both goroutines can send to the channel and exit. There is no leak.

You might want to receive both values to ensure that application detects an error when the first goroutine to send is successful and the second goroutine encounters an error.

```
var err error
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
  if e := <-errc; e != nil {
    err = e
  }
}
```

Because io.Copy does not return io.EOF, there's no need to check for io.EOF when collecting the errors.

The code can be simplified to use a single goroutine:

```
errc := make(chan error, 1)
go func() {
    _, err := io.Copy(rw1, rw2)
    errc <- err
}()

_, err := io.Copy(rw2, rw1)

if e := <-errc; e != nil {
   err = e
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Cerise. I have another question if I set the channel with size 2 so that the `errc` be set two times, but the `func transport ` only read one time and then exit, can this channel safety garbage?

Comment: Yes, you can prevent a leak by using a channel with capacity 2.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me

Comment: @vinllen Yikes, I missed that the channel in the question has buffer size of one.  There is no leak. See updated answer.